# Access the iterator variable in a coffeescript for loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to iterate though a list of objects and add an event handler to each.

The event handler needs a reference to the object that invoked the event.

The event handler triggers events within it's own scope so I'm managing it with an anonymous function and a thick arrow function.

I'd like to write something like the following

```
        for choice in allChoices
          choice.ee.on "choiceMade", () => @incrementChoicesMade choice
```

Of course that doesn't work, because the `choice` variable gets overwritten with each loop, so all objects events pass on the last object in the allChoices array.

If I were to handwrite vanilla javascript to do this, I'd write something like,

```
var _i, _len, _this = this; 

for (_i = 0, _len = allChoices.length; _i < _len; _i++) { 
  allChoices[_i].ee.on("choiceMade", function() { 
    return _this.incrementChoicesMade(allChoices[_i]); 
  });
}
```

is there a pure coffeescript way to implement this?

Comment: Executive summary: CoffeeScript has `do` for wrapping a loop's body in a SIF specifically for this purpose.

Comment: many thanks! Saved me quite a bit of head scratching